# How to filter any column parquet in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2, parquet

I store  data in hdfs as parquet format.
I write mapred to run this data success , and i want to filter any colum input in map,

How to filter any colum parquet in hadoop mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `parquet.read.schema` proterty in your mr job configuration, specify the schema string that contains the column you want(its a projection of the file's parquet schema).
  of course ,use the `ExampleInputFormat.class`.

I had been puzzled with this question for a long time until I read the source code `ParquetInputFormat.java GroupReadSuport.java` and so on.The ParquetInputFormat use the request schema to read.